# how to pass requestBody and requestParam in axios?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, rest, axios, request

I want to pass two parameters in axios post method one as requestBody and one as requestParam and also i need to pass authHeader as a header .

This is the axios method to post new senior with his image:

```
create(data,file) {

return http.post("/addSenior", data,{ headers: authHeader()});
```

}

and this is the controller with two parameters :

```
    @PostMapping("/addSenior")
    @ResponseBody
     @Operation(security = {@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearer-key")})
    public long addSenior(@RequestBody Senior s,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws Exception{
        
         FileDB attachment = null;
          String downloadURl = "";
       
            attachment = storageService.store(file);
            downloadURl = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                    .path("/download/")
                    .path(attachment.getId())
                    .toUriString();
          
        return seniorServiceImpl.addSenior(s,attachment.getId());
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you need to send a file along with some other data in spring mvc, you can use [`@RequestPart`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html) instead of `@RequestParam`. In your case, you can use something like this:

```
public long addSenior(@RequestPart Senior s, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
```

Comment: first i appreciate your interaction secondly , i want to know how to pass those two parts in axios method with header token